# How to copy photo in device's photo gallery to local path

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I have found lots of answers regarding how to download and save online photos to the app's cache or temporary directory. However, I need to know how to copy an image from the device's local gallery to the app's cache.

The reason for this [is a strange problem with iOS, where attempting to upload images to Firebase, using paths of images in the gallery, always fails in a physical device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58630680/flutter-firebase-storage-attempting-to-upload-images-from-gallery-generates-un) and always works in iOS simulator and Android (both physical and simulated). In the app I am building I also have the ability to take photos, which are saved to the app's directories by the camera app, and those uploads work fine. I need to try and first copy the images to my cache, to test if it will allow me to upload them to firebase successfully. I am using [multi_image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker) to get the local paths of the selected images from the gallery, all I need is to know, once I have those paths, how to copy a single one of those files to my app's temp directory (I use path_provider to get the appropriate path to temp directory).

It probably isn't a permissions issue because I have both Camera and Photo Library permissions in my plist.info, I get prompted for access and I can access the gallery without a problem when using the multi picker.

I have tried looking at the camera plugin's files and figure out how it does it, but no luck, I get lost once the plugin calls native methods.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: what do you want, just select the image from photo gallery and save in local cache or app cache?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ended up finding a solution that made it more efficient. I used the flutter_image_compress package to compress the images selected from the gallery (which I needed to do) and it includes the option to specify a new target path to save the compressed image.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress

It still seems strange that one must copy the images to a different location in order to upload them using Firebase. There must be some setting that will not allow the gallery photos to be uploaded from a physical device, that is not present in iOS simulator.